# Long range interface between a Raspberry Pi and a smartphone?

Tags: wifi, smartphones, raspberry-pi

I would like to control a **Raspberry Pi 4** with my smartphone (for my drone). Now I'm looking for an interface between the RPi and my Android phone.

**Requirements**:

- Control with a web interface or app
- Range: at least **1 km (0.62 miles)**.
- Data rate: I don't need a high data rate, because I don't want a camera live stream. I only want to send small commands, like forward, backward, ...
- Fast connection -> max. 0.5 second: Phone -> RPi
- No license (for special frequencies)
- One-time purchase -> No monthly fees

Here are some that I have looked at, but do not meet my requirements:

### - Use a sim card for the RPi:

- Websocket connection over a server -> web interface
- Unlimited range
- **Monthly fees**

### - Use the RPi as Access Point

- Connect the phone with the RPi-Wifi -> web interface
- **I think: to low range**

### - Connect my phone with a self-built antenna e.g. with RFM95W

- Connect the antenna with USB-C to my phone
- App
- **I must program a driver**

### - Bluetooth

- **To low range**

Thanks for your Hardware Recommendations!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Question moved to [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101860/long-range-interface-between-a-raspberry-pi-and-a-smartphone/101866#101866)**

Visit [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101860/long-range-interface-between-a-raspberry-pi-and-a-smartphone/101866#101866) for the solution.